# how to remove dash/hypen from solr?

Tags: search, solr, solr4

Currently I am facing some trouble while doing search in solr.

We have four records which are as below :-

1) Coperion KTron Feeder
2) K-Tron Twin Chocolate
3) K-Tron Feeder 
4) K-Tron Twin Revenue

While I try to search data using below keywords, it was returning to me different results.

1) ktron - 4 results
2) KTron - 4 results
3) k-tron - 3 results (Expected 4 results)
4) K-Tron - 3 results (Expected 4 results)

I am not sure what was wrong in below schema.xml file.

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" />
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Any help will be great.

Comment: What is the data type of the field. Is it text? If yes, then [this] (https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory) is the link you have to see and generateWordParts is the attribut you have to check for indexing. Happy Learning

Comment: It is already there but still it didn't provide me the result that i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with below field type

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
      <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>       
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" preserveOriginal="1" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Comment: can you please add which fields were modified

Comment: If I use splitoncasechange as per your suggestion, then it will split K-Tron into two words k and tron which i was not looking for the output. I was looking for ktron as single word to search while I enter K-Tron into search text box

Comment: @Ramzy : catenateWords="1".

Comment: didn't work any solution. It became nightmare for me.

Answer (score 0):

In query part of your definition, use catenateWords="0". This is the part used to combine the words, based on delimiters.

```
<analyzer type="query">
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" />
</analyzer>
```